# Find last row in range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm having a little trouble with finding the last row.

What I am trying to do is find the last row in column "A", then use that to find the last row within a range.

Example of Data:

[image: Example of data]

```
 1) LR_wbSelect = wbshtSelect.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 22

 2) LR_wbSelectNew = wbshtSelect.cells(LR_wbSelect, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

I am using the last row in column "A" as the data from row 29 down will always be the same length, the rows used in column "B" from row 29 can be a varying number of rows.

So I am trying to use `LR_wbSelect` in column "A" to get my starting last Row, then within `LR_wbSelectNew` using it as the starting point to look up from.

This works when the column I set to "A", `LR_wbSelectNew` gives me the row of "17", but when I change the column in `LR_wbSelectNew` to "B" it doesn't give the correct last row of "18".

I can change the column to "C, D, E, F" and the code works fine, but the only column that I can use is "B" because it will always have data in it, where the rest of that row could have a blank cell.

**After doing some testing on the sheet, by pressing CRTL & Up from the lastring point of `LR_wbSelect` column "B" ignores the data in the rows and go to the row where it find data. I can't see a reason why Excel doesn't think there is data in these cells?**

Comment: you can try to find the `Max` lastrow in both columns A and B.

Comment: @ShaiRado. Thanks for the response, I have tried my option with a dummy set of data in a different workbook, which gives me the correct results i need, but when i try and use it in the correct document is doesnt want to work. I will update the question to better show the problem.

Comment: still not sure what is the result you are trying to achieve ? You want to read the last row In Column B before the 10 empty rows (which means row 18) ? or you want to get row 31 ? (last row with data in Column B) ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, i want to get the last row in column B and get row 18 as a result. I have found that when pressing control and the up arrow in column be it skips the populated cells in that column and takes to the top of the page.

Comment: see my answer below and let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: @ShaiRado, apologies, it turns out excel thinks cells that have formulas but not displaying a value are populated, so it skips over them, is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: try my modified code, added a section to my code under `******Edit 1******` - it ignores cells that have formulas inside

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are mulitple results and methods when searching for the LastRow (in Column B).

When using `Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` you will get the last row with data in Column B (it ignores rows with spaces, and goes all the way down).

When using:

```
 With wbshtSelect.Range("B10").CurrentRegion
     LR_wbSelectNew = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
 End With
```

You are searching for the last row with data in Column B of the `CurrentRegion`, that starts from cell B10, untill the first line without data (it stops on the first row with empty row).

Full Code:

```
Sub GetLastRow()

Dim wbshtSelect         As Worksheet
Dim LR_wbSelectNew      As Long

' modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name
Set wbshtSelect = Sheets("Sheet2")

' find last row with data in Column B
With wbshtSelect
    LR_wbSelectNew = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With
' for debug only
Debug.Print LR_wbSelectNew ' >>result 31

' find last row with data in Column B at current regioun starting at cell B10
With wbshtSelect.Range("B10").CurrentRegion
    LR_wbSelectNew = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With
' for debug only
Debug.Print LR_wbSelectNew ' >> result 18

End Sub
```

**Edit1**: code searches for last row for cells with values (it ignores blank cells with formulas inside).

```
Sub GetLastRow()

Dim wbshtSelect         As Worksheet
Dim LR_wbSelectNew      As Long

' modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name
Set wbshtSelect = Sheets("Sheet2")

' find last row with data in Column B at current regioun starting at cell B10
With wbshtSelect.Range("B10").CurrentRegion
    LR_wbSelectNew = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With

Dim Rng         As Range    
Set Rng = wbshtSelect.Range("B10:B" & LR_wbSelectNew)

' find last row inside the range, ignore values inside formulas
LR_wbSelectNew = Rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("B10"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

' for debug
Debug.Print LR_wbSelectNew  ' << result 18 (with formulas in the range)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this piece of code helps !

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox LastRow
End Sub
```

Comment: this code returns "1" on a blank sheet, how is this possible? I want it to return if there is no value inside.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for a way to find the last row in a **non-contiguous** range. Most responses here only check one column at a time so I created a few different functions to solve this problem. I will admit, though, that my `.Find()` implementation is essentially the same as Shai Rado's answer.

**Implementation 1 - Uses `Range().Find()` in reverse order**

```
Function LastRowInRange_Find(ByVal rng As Range) As Long
    
    'searches range from bottom up stopping when it finds anything (*)
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = rng.Find( What:="*", _
                            After:=rng.Parent.Cells(rng.row, rng.Column), _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                            
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        LastRowInRange_Find = rngFind.row
    Else
        LastRowInRange_Find = rng.row
    End If
    
End Function
```

**Implementation 2 - Uses `Range().End(xlUp)` on each column**

```
Function LastRowInRange_xlUp(ByVal rng As Range) As Long
    
    Dim lastRowCurrent As Long
    Dim lastRowBest As Long

    'loop through columns in range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = rng.Column To rng.Column + rng.Columns.count - 1
        If rng.Rows.count < Rows.count Then
            lastRowCurrent = Cells(rng.row + rng.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row
        Else
            lastRowCurrent = Cells(rng.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row
        End If
        
        If lastRowCurrent > lastRowBest Then
            lastRowBest = lastRowCurrent
        End If
    Next i
    
    If lastRowBest < rng.row Then
        LastRowInRange_xlUp = rng.row
    Else
        LastRowInRange_xlUp = lastRowBest
    End If
    
End Function
```

**Implementation 3 - Loops through an Array in reverse order**

```
Function LastRowInRange_Array(ByVal rng As Range) As Long

    'store range's data as an array
    Dim rngValues As Variant
    rngValues = rng.Value2

    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'loop through range from left to right and from bottom upwards
    For i = LBound(rngValues, 2) To UBound(rngValues, 2)                'columns
        For j = UBound(rngValues, 1) To LBound(rngValues, 1) Step -1    'rows

            'if cell is not empty
            If Len(Trim(rngValues(j, i))) > 0 Then
                If j > lastRow Then lastRow = j

                Exit For
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

    If lastRow = 0 Then
        LastRowInRange_Array = rng.row
    Else
        LastRowInRange_Array = lastRow + rng.row - 1
    End If
    
End Function
```

I have not tested which of these implementations works fastest on large sets of data, but I would imagine that the winner would be `_Array` since it is not looping through each cell on the sheet individually but instead loops through the data stored in memory. However, I have included all 3 for variety :)

---

**How to use**

To use these functions, you drop them into your code sheet/module, specify a range as their parameter, and then they will return the "lowest" filled row within that range.

Here's how you can use any of them to solve the initial problem that was asked:

```
Sub answer()

    Dim testRange As Range
    Set testRange = Range("A1:F28")
    
    MsgBox LastRowInRange_Find(testRange)
    MsgBox LastRowInRange_xlUp(testRange)
    MsgBox LastRowInRange_Array(testRange)
    
End Sub
```

Each of these will return `18`.

Comment: I am not a fan of using `CurrentRegion` because a lot of the times that I may use this function, there are gaps in the data which cause `CurrentRegion` to give incorrect answers

Comment: If you find passing a certain range to one of these breaks it, please comment to let me know and I'll fix it!

Answer (score 2):

If your wbshtSelect is defined as worksheet and you have used set to define the specific worksheet, you can use this.

```
 Dim LastRow As Long

 wbshtSelect.UsedRange ' Refresh UsedRange
 LastRow = wbshtSelect.UsedRange.Rows(wbshtSelect.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
```

Otherwise take a look here http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm

Comment: UsedRange is usually better than CurrentRegion (which is in the accepted answer). CurrentRegion will stop at gaps in the sheet, UsedRange will find the very end instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
LR_wbSelectNew = wbshtSelect.cells(LR_wbSelect, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Why are you using "LR_wbSelect" as the row counter? If you want to know the last row of column 'B', you should use Rows.count

Rows.count --> Returns maximum number of rows (which is 1048576 for Excel 2007 and up)
End(xlUp) --> Moves the pointer upward to the last used row

So, 
 cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row --> This moves the pointer to the last row if the column 'A' (as if you are pressing Crtl+Up keys when A1048576 cell is selected)

So, use Rows.count to select the last row for column 'B' as well. If you have some specific requirement related to LR_wbSelect, please mention it.

Alternatively, if you want to know the last row used in a sheet, you may use the below:

```
mySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

Comment: ArindamD, I have update my question to hopefully better explain the situtation.

Answer (score 1):

```
LR_wbSelect = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple function that return last row no. in specific sheet.
It takes the last address in UsedRange and retrieve last row number.
Feel to free change the code and use standard range insead of UsedRange.

```
Function FindLastRow(wsToCheck As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim str As String
    str = wsToCheck.UsedRange.AddressLocal()
    FindLastRow = Right(str, InStr(1, StrReverse(str), "$") - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range().End` will bring you to the end of a code block.  If the starting cell is empty, it brings you the the first used cell or the last cell.  It the cells is not empty it brings you to the last used cell.  For this reason, you need to test whether or not the cell in column B is to determine whether to use `LR_wbSelectNew` as the last row.

```
With wbshtSelect
    LR_wbSelect = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 22

    If .Cells(LR_wbSelect, "B") <> "" Then
        LR_wbSelectNew = LR_wbSelect
    Else
        LR_wbSelectNew = .Cells(LR_wbSelect, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
End With
```

This code defines a Target range that extends from A1 to the last row in column a - 22 and extends 10 columns.

```
Dim Target As Range
With wbshtSelect
    Set Target = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-22)).Resize(, 10)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    'This is sure method to find or catch last row in any column even   'if  some cell are blank in-between. (Excel-2007)` 
'This works even if sheet is not active

    'mycol is the column you want to get last row number

for n=1048575 to 1 step -1
myval=cells(n,mycol)
if myval<>"" then
mylastrow=n 'this is last row in the column
exit for
end if
next

ret=msgbox("Last row in column-" & mycol & "is=" & mylastrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shai Rado's first solution is a great one**, but for some it might need a bit more elaboration:

```
 Dim rngCurr, lastRow
 rngCurr = wbshtSelect.Range("B10").CurrentRegion
 lastRow = rngCurr.Rows(rngCurr.Rows.Count).Row
```

If you want to know the last used row in the entire worksheet:

```
 Dim rngCurr, lastRow
 rngCurr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
 lastRow = rngCurr.Rows(rngCurr.Rows.Count).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim FirstRow, LastRow As long

Set rng = Selection

With rng

 FirstRow = ActiveCell.Row

 LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Backing off from the range to the worksheet will get you the whole sheet extents of the range used on the sheet (which may be smaller than you expect if the sheet doesn't have data in the top rows; but it does include internal blanks)

***TheRange.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count***

If there is no data in the top rows, the following will get you the first row which you need to add to the above to get the highest row number

***TheRange.End(xlDown).Row***

So
***Dim TheRange as Range
Dim MaxRow as Long
MaxRow = TheRange.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + TheRange.End(xlDown).Row***

Will get the highest row number with data (but not the whole sheet)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Before getting into complex coding why not build something on the below principle:

MaxRow = Application.Evaluate("MIN(ROW(A10:C29)) + ROWS(A10:C29) - 1")