# Excel VBA: Determine the last used row using a named range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to determine the last used row inside a range, using a named range I created.

Here is how I am doing it.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim textboxValue As String, lastUsedRow As Long
    textboxValue = UserForm.TextBox1
    lastUsedRow = .Range(textboxValue ).Rows.Count
    Cells(lastUsedRow).Select
End With
```

[image]
This is what's in the worksheet so the last used row should be the one with the word "No."

[image]
But the selected last used row is a cell with nothing in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Find last row in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650508/excel-vba-find-last-row-in-range)

Comment: `Cells(lastUsedRow)` - you haven't provided a row and a column

Comment: If I put a column it is still to the wrong cell. Different cell but still the wrong one.

Comment: What does the `UserForm.TextBox1`have to do with the spreadsheet? Do you enter the name of a named range there, or what is its purpose?

Comment: `lastUsedRow = .Range(textboxValue).Rows.Count` - let's look at what this does. The `textboxValue` is used as a cell reference - probably the address of a range. `.Rows.Count` literally counts the number of rows that exist (empty or otherwise) in this range. So if the address in `textboxValue` for instance is `D8:F11` - which spans 4 rows (8, 9, 10 and 11), the returned value is 4

Comment: @CLR so is there a way to determine the last used row using a named range?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is this...

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim textboxValue As String, lastUsedRow As Long, i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    textboxValue = UserForm.TextBox1
    Set rng = .Range("textboxValue")
    For i = rng.Cells(1).Offset(rng.Cells.Count - 1).Row To rng.Cells(1).Row Step -1
        If .Cells(i, rng.Columns(1).Column) <> "" Then
            lastUsedRow = .Cells(i, rng.Columns(1).Column).Row
            MsgBox lastUsedRow
            .Cells(i, rng.Columns(1).Column).Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    If lastUsedRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "textboxValue range is completely empty.", vbExclamation
    End If
End With
```