# Need to set only the last row in a selection range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to format only the last row in a pre-selected area.

I have for example this code for selecting row number 2

```
Set PH = Range(Cells(Selection.Row + 1, Selection.Column), Cells(Selection.Row + 1, (Selection.Column + Selection.Columns.Count) - 1))
```

The remaining rows in the selection can be different from time to time, why I need a dynamic code to set only the last row in the selection.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650508/excel-vba-find-last-row-in-range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Find last row in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650508/excel-vba-find-last-row-in-range)