# VBA & Excel: Selecting the row below a selection

Tags: excel, vba

I know this question may get asked a lot, but I haven't been able to find or understand the answer for exactly what I am looking for.

I am learning VBA in excel for the first time today and I am trying to auto-format a table of values and want this to work on different range sizes.

I am stuck on how to select the row underneath the last row in my selection and format it.

My code so far is:

```
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

Selection.Rows("1:1").Interior.Color = 12155648

With Selection.Rows("1:1").Font

    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1

    .Bold = True

End With



Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

Selection.Cells(Selection.Rows.Count, Selection.Columns.Count).Select

   

Selection.Interior.Color = 12632256

Selection.Font.Bold = True

Selection.Range("A1").Value = "Total"
```

What I want to happen:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyxMu.png)
[image]

[Desired Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2149W.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't a common question because most programmers learn on their second day (that's tomorrow in your schedule) not to "Select" anything and use the *Range* object instead. Then your code would look more like this:-

```
Private Sub Snippet()

    Dim Rng     As Range

    With Selection.CurrentRegion
        .Rows(1).Interior.Color = 12155648
        With .Rows(1).Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .Bold = True
        End With
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count, .Column).Resize(1, .Columns.Count)
    End With
    
    With Rng
        .Interior.Color = 12632256
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(1).Value = "Total"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

What about making it into an *actual* table

```
Sub Demo()
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, , xlYes)
        .Name = "MyTable" ' optional
        .ShowTotals = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: I like where your head is at, however the point of formatting the tables as such was to match the existing formats of tables in a very lengthy annual report. And to match the formats of these tables from previous years as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following method, assuming your table start from `B4`:

```
Sub ty()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row + 1

With Sheet1.Range("B4").Resize(1, 5)
    .Interior.Color = 12155648
    .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

Sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 2).Value = "Total"

With Sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 2).Resize(1, 5)
    .Interior.Color = 12632256
    .Font.Bold = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps better: `lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: I was trying to make the macro such that it would work on any table that begins anywhere within the sheet.

Comment: @BigBen, amazing, doing it reverse way. But there is better way to find last row when top few row is empty `Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows(Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`, i find this long time ago on one of the Stackoverflow question but not able to trace it back, this is other link i got it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650508/find-last-row-in-range

Comment: @998024562165, yes, you can just change the range base on your table will do, please try it out

Comment: Nope, `UsedRange` isn't reliable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: @BigBen, i never find it unreliable, as I will delete all the row before upload new data, one of favorite method is still `usedrange` until today :)

Comment: @Kin Siang, I was aware I could change the range in the excel but if I wanted to use this on multiple different tables in a single spreadsheet I would have had to go in and edit the code each time. I was looking for a way using current region so that I wouldnt have to edit.

Comment: It is fine, as long as you find a solution.